# How to access external port in docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I would like to use my docker-compose config for development purposes and run frontend, backend, nginx for routing services to run and start together. For now I'm using also kubernetes port-forwarding in order to get to my neo4j db. What I want to achieve is to use mapped port inside docker containers, ie. external port should be also visible inside the docker. It runs without docker smoothly but cannot inside containers. My docker-compose file looks like this, nothing fancy:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  lan:

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 3050:80
    depends_on:
      - client
      - api

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app

  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=neo4j://neo4j:password@localhost:7687
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_LOGIN=neo4j
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_PASS=password
```

Unfortunately I'm getting error as it is not forwarder inside my docker api container. To forward the port I'm using (after getting authenticated): 
`kubectl port-forward svc/neo4j-ee-neo4j 7687:7687` but of course it is only available on my host.

Comment: You cannot access a port on your host from the docker containers. I haven't tried this myself, but if I was in your situation one thing I could try is to build a docker image with kubectl in it, mount kubectl config, and run it from the docker container to create a port-forward to the k8s cluster. Then other containers should be able to connect to that new container. Again, I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Can you run everything in Docker Compose, or everything in Kubernetes, and not try to mix the two?

Comment: Well I could try but I’m not sure I can do that. Neo4J is deployed in google cloud (not by me and it is not mantained by me either) but all other services are running locally in dev mode(react part, express part, nginx). What I want to achieve is to start and run all those services at once with a simple command as it was in docker compose world (thru `docker-compose up`).

Answer (score 3):

add `network_mode: "host"` to the service properties, so it will share the host interface.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Comment: But then there is no network connecting all containers, isn't it?